# Pandas resampling with category variable

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I would like to resample a dataframe hourly and keep the category variable, how can I do that efficiently. I normally use `df = df.resample('h').sum()` but this does not work with my category variable. Any idea?

```
date  = ['2015-02-03 23:00:00','2015-02-03 23:30:00','2015-02-04 00:00:00','2015-02-04 00:30:00']
value = [33.24  , 31.71  , 34.39  , 34.49 ]
value2 = [2*x for x in value]
value3 = [3*x for x in value]
cat = ['a','a','b','b']
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':value,'value2':value2,'value3':value3,'index':date,'category':cat})

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['index'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df.drop(['index'],axis=1,inplace=True)

print(df.head())
                    value  value2  value3    category
index                                     
2015-02-03 23:00:00  33.24   66.48   99.72    a
2015-02-03 23:30:00  31.71   63.42   95.13    a
2015-02-04 00:00:00  34.39   68.78  103.17    b
2015-02-04 00:30:00  34.49   68.98  103.47    b
```

expected result:

```
                     value  value2  value3    category
index                                     
2015-02-03 23:00:00  64.95   129.9   194.85    a
2015-02-04 00:00:00  68.88   137.76  206.64    b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.resample.html) - it means chain `groupby` with `resample`:

```
df = df.groupby('category').resample('h').sum()
print (df)
                              value  value2  value3
category index                                     
a        2015-02-03 23:00:00  64.95  129.90  194.85
b        2015-02-04 00:00:00  68.88  137.76  206.64
```

Or is possible use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['category', pd.Grouper(freq='h')]).sum()
print (df)
                              value  value2  value3
category index                                     
a        2015-02-03 23:00:00  64.95  129.90  194.85
b        2015-02-04 00:00:00  68.88  137.76  206.64
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `sum()` aggregation is not meaningful for categories. You have to explicitly define what aggregation you want for the categorical column.

For example, if you would like to pick the first value of the categorical, you can do:

```py
df = df.resample('h').apply({"value":"sum", "value2":"sum", "value3":"sum", "category":"first"})
print(df)

                     value  value2  value3 category
index                                              
2015-02-03 23:00:00  64.95  129.90  194.85        a
2015-02-04 00:00:00  68.88  137.76  206.64        b
```